# Save in other tables (DACs) from a Graph

Tags: acumatica

Let's say that I have three database tables. Table1, Table2, Table3. I have created their DACs and their corresponding graph for each Graph1, Graph2, and Graph3.

Now I have created a screen for Graph1 which is showing data from Table1. But when a user clicks a particular Action Button in this screen, I want to save data in Tables 2 and 3. I want to insert multiple records in each table.

I don't think it makes sense to add Tables2 and Table 3 as Data Views (PXSelect properties) in Graph 1 because they will only be used when the user triggers the Action.

What's the recommended way to achieve this in Acumatica? For example, should I use PXDatabase.Update or should I create an instance of Graph2 and Graph3, call update on their Data Views and call PressSave? Also, would it be possible to wrap everything in a PXTransactionScope?

Comment: Persisting the data with Graph1 for all Tables should be fine. You can mark the updates in graph 1 for tables 2 and 3 from your action and persist/save. If the other graphs have business logic on them that needs to execute during updates then it might make sense to split out the updates. Just an option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you kindly explain in more detail how to 'mark the updates in graph 1 for tables 2 and 3'? What is the approach to 'mark' the updates please?

Comment: add the view(s) for the tables to your graph1 and then its just viewname.Update(theRowUpdating); before you persist. You will need to get your records via a PXSelect, then update your values, then call your viewname.Update() and pass in the DAC object you are updating. Repeat for all rows to be updated and then all changes are updated in the graph1 cache. Persisting/PressSave will save all values at once without needing to wrap in a transaction exclusively

Comment: Thanks, sounds good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below a code sample showing how to save changes in a single transaction from multiple BLC instances:

```
public class MyGraph1 : PXGraph<MyGraph1>
{
    public PXAction<MyDAC> MultiGraphAction;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Magic Action")]
    protected virtual void multiGraphAction()
    {
        using (var ts = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            // To save changes made in MyGraph1
            Actions.PressSave();

            // To save changes in MyGraph2
            var myGraph2 = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MyGraph2>();
            // Place here data manipulation logic for myGraph2
            myGraph2.Actions.PressSave();

            // To save changes in MyGraph2
            var myGraph3 = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MyGraph3>();
            // Place here data manipulation logic for myGraph3
            myGraph3.Actions.PressSave();

            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```