# Graph only saving 1 row in secondary graph - Acumatica C#

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am currently trying to save form fields to their associated graphs via a PXAction method. This post that I have followed has been useful: [Save in other tables (DACs) from a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364638/save-in-other-tables-dacs-from-a-graph)

The code I have currently works, however, my secondary graph (LoanDetail) will only save the entered row to it's associated table, and not log the previous rows that have been entered. The first graph everything saves fine. This is my code:

```
public class DetailMaint : PXGraph<DetailMaint>
{
    public PXSelect<LoanDetail> LoanDetails;
}

public class LoanMaint : PXGraph<LoanMaint>
{
    //First section of form to save to primary table
    public SelectFrom<AllLoans>.View LoanView;
    //Second section of form to save to second table
    public SelectFrom<LoanDetail>.View DetailView;

    public PXAction<AllLoans> SaveButton;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Save Button")]
    protected void saveButton()
    {
        using (var ts = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            Actions.PressSave();
            
            var detailGraph = CreateInstance<DetailMaint>();
            detailGraph.Actions.PressSave();

            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See following : https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/07/select-multiple-documents-into-one-grid.html

Comment: This looks good, thank you !